# Help with Syncopation

Tags: theory, beginner, syncopation

[image]I have an assignment with a simple rhythm in 4/4 time. I am being asked to rewrite the rhythm as syncopated with one half beat before the start of the measure. I cant add a photo as it is too large to upload even with compression but the notes are as follows:

quarter, quarter, two eighths joined together, quarter

How would I syncopate this? I have tried reading around the concept but cant seem to grasp it. From what I can understand it is shifting the expected accent. In this case to the 2nd and 4th note

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The part "one half beat (eight note) _before_ the start of the measure" is important. Where would you place the notes if it said "one _quarter_ beat before the start of the measure"? Where would you place the notes if it said "one half beat _after_ the start of the measure?"

Answer (score 1):

Just so as to not COMPLETELY do your homework for you...

I've started with a slightly different original version.   This is what I think they're asking you to do to it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Syncopation is moving the emphasis of notes played. Normally, the first beat in a bar is more emphasised - slightly louder - than the rest, the third (in 4/4) being the next most emphasised. As in ***1*** - 2 - **3** - 4 - ***1*** - 2 - **3** - 4. By listening to how certain parts are emphasised, we can determine what time signature a piece has.

By putting that emphasis just *before* the new bar, and not actually having *any* emphasis at the beginning of the next, it throws things. Sometimes called a *push* note, as it pushes that emphasis early.

So in order to do that, there's a quaver (1/8 note) at the end of the previous bar, tied to the next note - usually a crotchet - at the beginning of the following bar. Now, the count is ***1*** - 2 - **3** - 4 ***&*** - (1) - 2 - **3** - 4.

As Laurence says, the 3rd beat can also be 'pushed', although the wording of the question doesn't necessarily expect that.